# Display a link in javascript if var is not empty. checking var endefined not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display a link in sweetalert html only if the var is not empty. Here is the code:

```
$('.patient-details').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this)
var name = $this.data('name');
var gender = $this.data('gender');
var age = $this.data('age');
var country = $this.data('country');
var address = $this.data('address');
var report = $this.data('report');
swal({
title: name,
html:
    "Gender: " + gender +"<br>" +
   "Age: " + age +"<br>" +
   "Country: " + country +"<br>" +
   "Address: " + address +"<br>" +
   (report!=undefined?'<a href="' + report + '" target="_blank">View Report</a>':''),
});
});
```

I need the report link to be displayed only if var report is not empty. Here is the code pen:
https://codepen.io/pamela123/pen/GOJZgo

I tried

```
if(report){
report = $this.data('report');
}
```

report is "**undefined**". report!=undefined is not working.

But how not to display the report link inside the html if report is empty ??

I know it is a simple javascript question, but being a newbie i could not get further.

Comment: Just put a check if it is blank, then do not include the anchor.

Comment: It seems like your variable has the content `"undefined"` according to your question. This indicates that it is a string. Which will lead the if statement to be true

Comment: @ kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Which is exactly my question. It is not working as can be seen in the codepen.
https://codepen.io/pamela123/pen/GOJZgo

Comment: @Pamela can't see that the report value is undefined. Can you provide a codepen when it is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the data in a separate variable.

Then check if `report` is not `undefined`. If not, add it to the variable.

```
$('.patient-details').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this)
  var name = $this.data('name');
  var gender = $this.data('gender');
  var age = $this.data('age');
  var country = $this.data('country');
  var address = $this.data('address');
  var report = $this.data('report');

  var htmlData = "Gender: " + gender + "<br>" +
      "Age: " + age + "<br>" +
      "Country: " + country + "<br>" +
      "Address: " + address + "<br>";
  if( report !== undefined && report != "" ) {
    htmlData +=  '<a href="' + report + '" target="_blank">View Report</a>'
  }
  swal({
    title: name,
    html: htmlData
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry..Not working.

Comment: After changing if( report)..it will work. But not if report !== undefined. which was my question. Wonder why report !== undefined is not working ??

Comment: Works for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzbpBK

Comment: I have added `&& report`. With that addition it works when the `data-report` attribute is empty **and** if the attribute isn't set at all (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VrLPVQ)

Comment: Then try the code again, I've changed it in my answer

Comment: You have added && report != ""  and it will work fine. But not with report !== undefined.

Comment: The code in my answer works... see these test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/6ygkvk42/

Comment: Somebody down voted my question. I don't know why ??

Comment: Thank you so much. I will accept your answer as the best. Please consider removing my down votes too, if you don't mind.

Comment: I didn't downvote...

Answer (score 1):

You Can Update your Code as below

```
var htmlTemplate="Gender: " + gender +"<br>" +"Age: " + age +"<br>" + "Country: " + country +"<br>" + "Address: " + address +"<br>" ;
if(report){
   htmlTemplate+= '<a href="' + report + '" target="_blank">View Report</a>';
}
swal({
title: name,
html: htmlTemplate,
});
```

Comment: Why is report !== undefined not working??? Your solution works. But my question was why undefined is not working ??

Comment: Since you are passing **data-report=""**, that is why it's not working for undefined

Comment: if( report !== undefined && report != "" ) will work. As i am getting the value from a DB. In some cases it may be empty. Please See the accepted answer.

Comment: If You remove report !="", that code will also not work. I would recommend you to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators, you will get more clarity on conditions

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.patient-details').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this)
var name = $this.data('name');
var gender = $this.data('gender');
var age = $this.data('age');
var country = $this.data('country');
var address = $this.data('address');
var report = $this.data('report');
swal({
title: name,
html:
    "Gender: " + gender +"<br>" +
   "Age: " + age +"<br>" +
   "Country: " + country +"<br>" +
   "Address: " + address +"<br>" +(typeof report !== "undefined" && report != ""?'<a href="' + report + '" target="_blank">View Report</a>':'')
    ,
});
});
```

Comment: report!=null? is not working.

Comment: use typeof report != "undefined" instead of that

Comment: Sorry..That is not working either.

Comment: Check the above code that will work (typeof report !== "undefined"?'<a href="' + report + '" target="_blank">View Report</a>':'')